# Enumerated list, labels like 1/3, 2/3, 3/3

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'd like to have an enumerated list that ① supports `resume` and ② uses the notation `n of N`, e.g. (in ASCII)

```
1/4. Bla.
2/4. Bla bla.

Some additional bla bla,

3/4. from my balcone.
4/4. Bla bla.
```

I *imagine* that I could use a counter and possibly a two pass compilation (but I don't know how *exactly* do that), but I wonder <strike>if</strike> that some package already provides the requested features.

Comment: The [totcount package](https://ctan.org/pkg/totcount) should be able to do that. #2, at least.

Comment: @user574859 Questions in a written test?

Comment: Note that the label has to fit into \labelwidth-\labelsep, so 10/11 will probably cause problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `enumitem` you can save the final value of the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{gbenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[gbenumerate]{
  wide,
  label=\arabic*/\gbenumall.,
}

\providecommand\gbenumall{0}% initial value

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \write\@auxout{\gdef\string\gbenumall{\the\value{gbenumeratei}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gbenumerate}
\item this is the first item
\item this is the second item
\end{gbenumerate}

Some text in between

\begin{gbenumerate}[resume]
\item this is the third item
\item this is the fourth item
\end{gbenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A bit more complex if you want to use `gbenumerate` several times with reset. In this case you have to say when to reset and to save the last value. I suggest enclosing the parts in a suitable environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{gbenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[gbenumerate]{
  wide,
  label=\arabic*/\unexpanded{\gbenum{\thesubgbenumerate}}.,
  resume
}
\newcounter{subgbenumerate}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subgbenumerate}
 {%
  \stepcounter{subgbenumerate}%
 }
 {\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\storegbenum{\thesubgbenumerate}{\the\value{gbenumeratei}}}}
\newcommand{\storegbenum}[2]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname gbenum@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\gbenum}[1]{\ifcsname gbenum@#1\endcsname\csname gbenum@#1\endcsname\else 0\fi}
\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subgbenumerate}
\begin{gbenumerate}
\item this is the first item
\item this is the second item
\end{gbenumerate}

Some text in between

\begin{gbenumerate}
\item this is the third item
\item this is the fourth item
\end{gbenumerate}
\end{subgbenumerate}

Some text in between.

\begin{subgbenumerate}
\begin{gbenumerate}
\item this is the first item
\item this is the second item
\end{gbenumerate}

Some text in between

\begin{gbenumerate}
\item this is the third item
\item this is the fourth item
\item this is the fifth item
\end{gbenumerate}
\end{subgbenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should the OP realize that what they really want is, using the `gbenumerate` environment many times in the same document, resetting the counter… should they ask a new question, or they can count on your benevolence?

Comment: @gboffi I added the code

Comment: Shouldn't enumitem already be saving the last value for use with [resume]?

Comment: @JohnKormylo But not in the `aux` file, just in memory.

Comment: @gboffi Depending on your use case, you might be able to embed the `subgbenumerate` code in another environment you use.

Comment: Thank you very much.